# How do they know the numbers of the energy pie chart of the universe?

Tags: cosmology, universe, dark-matter, dark-energy, observable-universe

They say that the total energy of the universe consists of 4.9\% ordinary matter, 26.8\% dark matter and 68.3\% dark energy. I hear this pie part in virtually every lecture in cosmology. How do we know these numbers?[image]

Comment: Here is a link https://wmap.gsfc.nasa.gov/universe/uni_matter.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These numbers are determined by fitting precise observational data of the small anisotropies of the [cosmic microwave background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background), gathered by the [Planck spacecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_(spacecraft)), to the standard model of cosmology, the [Lambda-CDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model) model.

In this successful model based on the [Friedmann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations), there are three ingredients that make up the contents of our universe: [dark energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy) (that’s the “Lambda”), “cold” (i.e., non-relativistic) [dark matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter) (that’s the “CDM”), and ordinary matter. Radiation provides a negligible fraction of the current energy density.

Comment: So these values are determined by fitting them as input parameters inthe model and optimizing?

Comment: As you can see in the “Parameters” section of Wikipedia’s Lambda-CDM article, this model has six independent parameters as inputs, but they don’t include these pie chart numbers. Instead, those three values are outputs among 10 *calculated* values. The “successes” section discusses how this model fits various peaks in the so-called TT spectrum, and then *predicts* various peaks in the TE and EE spectra, which are observed.